# "Unhandled exception" error when using a loop inside thread

Tags: c++, boost, multithreading

I got this error

`Unhandled exception at 0x0049b946 in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000090.`

and the error points to this line:

```
        // thread.hpp ln 56
        void run()
        {
            f(); // here <<
        }
```

When trying to run this code:

```
void frameFunc()
{
    for(;;)
    {
         //..........do something. it is too long to paste. (calculations)
    }
}

int main()
{
   boost::thread framethread(frameFunc);
   framethread.join();
   //........
}
```

The error will simply gone when I remove the loop in frameFunc.

Any kind of help would be appreciated :)

Comment: it is too long to paste. they're all game calculations (more for-loops, altering variables, updating objects: FMOD Ex update, sprite positions, etc.). nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you showed looks valid.  I think the problem is inside the code that is not shown.

Comment: You'll probably find that the code will still run fine if you remove only the contents of the loop...

Comment: Here is an example of why doing something many times may segfault: 1) int x[2];
int *p = x; *p=3;  2) p++; *p=4;  3) p++; *p = 7;<-- crash.